# Dropdown Ajax Laravel ( Append, onChange, Method not Allowed )

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, dropdown

i just learn about Ajax. I am so confused and getting error after following some tutorials. The plan is after we get the **id_program**, we can change or reload the page to show the data inside the dropdown menu after we clicks it. May someone help me please?

1.1 Database ( Program )

[image]

1.2 Inside **Payment**

[image]

1.3 Inside **actor**
[image]

---

2. DatabaseController.php

   ```
   public function data($id)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8585/api/v1/tables', [
            'query' => [
                'limit' => '100'
            ]
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['data'];
        $pay = Payment::get()->all();
        $pro = Program::select('nama')->where('name', $id)->get();
        $coba = Program::get()->all();
        foreach ($pro as $p) {
            $name = $p->name;
        }
        return view('database.index', compact('nama','data','pay','coba','pro','id'));
    }
   ```

---

3. Route

   ```
   Route::get('program/database/{database}', [DatabaseController::class,'data'])->name('database.data');
   ```

---

4. database.index

   ```
   <select id="id" class="form-control" filter>
           <option>Pilih Layanan...</option>
                @foreach ($coba as $id)
                     <option value="{{$id->id_program}}">{{ $id->nama}}</option>
                @endforeach
   </select>
   ```

---

5. Ajax Script

   $(function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
   });

   ```
        $(function(){
            $('#id').on('change',function(){
               number =$('#id').val();

                console.log(number)

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "{{route('database.data',lcfirst($name))}}",
                    cache : false,
                    data:function(d){
                        d.number = number; 
                        return d;
                    },

                    success: function(msg){
                        console.log('success')

                    },
                })
            })
        })
    });
   ```

---

6. Result (Error)

a. ( id_program = 1 ) **Correct** data output & **Method Not Allowed** error

[image]

b. ( id_program = 2 ) **Incorrect** data output & **Method Not Allowed** error

---

[image]

---

Thank you for the helps

Comment: you are doing a POST request on your ajax call, while you are declaring the route as Get

Comment: @didenetahi from some tutorials i follows, it set so. And after i try to change it to "GET", i got another error.

Comment: what errors you having after setting GET?

Comment: @didenetahi sorry, Sir. My bad. Now it fixed. I don't know how, i was just stressed out and clear cache laravel and close the browser. ||
But, i really not lying if i was getting error when i change it to "GET". I have been stucking in it for 1-2 hours :'D

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('program/database/{database}', [DatabaseController::class,'data'])->name('database.data');
```

see the "get" key word? You are declare this route as a GET route, but your AJAX method:

```
 $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : "{{route('database.data',lcfirst($name))}}",
     ....
```

is a POST request.

The solution is:

- if your request only GET some data (no create, no delete, no update,... any data), then `$.ajax({ type : 'GET', ....`
- if your request do modify data, then `Route::post('program....`